# how to tackle Arithmetic overflow in db2 functions

Tags: db2, user-defined-functions

When I run a user defined function db2 returns the following error

```
  SQL0802N  Arithmetic overflow or other arithmetic exception occurred.  
  SQLSTATE=22003
```

without giving me any indication about which function is the source of that error.
Is that any setting on db2 so that I can have something like a stack trace or better information. By just looking at that message I don't know where to start investigating.

Comment: Is it possible to share the code with us? or at least a snippet to reproduce the error.

Comment: Hi AngocA. I didn't put the code as it is too big and many functions are involved. At the end I found the error (see below) but still I didn't find an easy way to debug it or spot it..I was just lucky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the return type of your UDF. If it's something like `Decimal(5,2)`, but the function is trying to return something bigger than that, it would give this error. what does this function do?

You might try looking in the db2dump directory (~sqllib/db2dump) for error logs. Not sure if this is an error that gets logged though.

Comment: Hi. You are right. I found the error and an integer and a decimal with the wrong size were causing the issue. Unfortunately I have to say that I found the bug by luck; the log of db2 doesn't give too much indication.